# Is Cloudfare Workers KV available from IBM CIS

Tags: ibm-cloud

is the Cloudfare Workers KV key value store available through IBM CIS? Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: please ask this question in here : https://superuser.com/

Comment: Hi - IBM Cloud Support says it's not currently available.